# Disabling Viewstate Causes selected dropdown values to default to -1

Tags: asp.net

I don't get this.  So I disable viewstate on my .aspx page.  I then select options from 3 dropdown menus and then on submit check the values and they are all -1.  I put ViewState back on and do the same, select values and now in the submit event they're all set to a valid value for the SelectedIndex.

I don't get this.  I don't see how viewstate has anything to do with selecting values in a dropdown and then calling a server-side handler to pick up those selected values in order to do something with it and in order to get the actual valid SelectedIndex values that the user selected.  I don't see why it would give me a -1 if I disable viewstate for the SelectedIndex for each of those 3 dropdownlist controls.

Answer (score 1):

Either move your code that binds the dropdowns into Page_Init or surround them with

```
if (!IsPostPack) { ... }
```

Comment: The following links will help you understand why: http://john-sheehan.com/blog/net-cheat-sheets/ (Page Lifecycle Cheet Sheet) and Truly Understanding Viewstate: http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2008/02/19/truly-understanding-viewstate-comment-index.aspx

Comment: It has nothing to do with postback.  I already have it wrapped in !Page.IsPostback.  I'm submitting a form and those values should be sent to the server.  Postback is what is being sent back afterwards..which is what !IsPostback covers